# ¿Se puede duplicar una pregunta cuando la solución a esta no resuelve mi problema de igual modo?

Tags: discusión

Me explico mejor con un ejemplo

> Un usuario ***A*** tiene ***X*** problema en `PHP`
>   Un usuario ***B*** le responde al usuario ***A*** con ***Y*** respuesta y SOLUCIONA CORRECTAMENTE su 
>   ***X*** problema
>
> ---
>
> Un usuario ***C*** tiene ***X*** problema en `PHP` (nótese que es ***X***, mismo problema que usuario ***A***)
>   La respuesta ***Y*** del usuario ***B*** NO SOLUCIONA dicho problema del mismo modo en que se la solucionó a usuario ***A*** (sea porque son diferentes versiones de `PHP`, el problema quizá no sea en sí del código si no de alguna configuración y/o pre-requisito, etc...)

¿Se podría "duplicar" dicha pregunta para encontrar otra solución distinta a la original cuando esta no funciona y el problema sea el mismo?

NOTA: Usé `PHP` como ejemplo y di más o menos esa descripción porque he vivido esto anteriormente y las soluciones que he encontrado han servido en una u otra versión para el mismo problema, sin embargo creo que esto se puede dar en muchos otros más casos, como puede ser un problema con un servidor apache en un sistema operativo Ubuntu, Debian, Arch o cualquier otro

Espero haberme hecho entendido.

Comment: Claro que se puede :) Pero es necesario poner **explicitamente** que esa respuesta no te ha solucionado el problema por el motivo **M**

Comment: Como comenta Miquel,  además agregar el enlace de la pregunta que no soluciono el problema.

Comment: También sería bueno ver cada caso. Si por ejemplo pregunto sobre cadenas y la posible duplicada es sobre arreglos, nada que ver. Sin embargo, si se trata de una pregunta para un módulo con la versión 2.x y te votan a cierre con una pregunta que tiene la respuesta para la 1.x, lo más recomendable es publicar una respuesta en la posible pregunta duplicada indicando "aquí la solución para el módulo <foo> en la versión 2.x: <solución>" y votar a cierre.

Comment: Una pregunta es duplicada o no duplicada con independencia de que contenga enlaces a respuestas que no solucionan la pregunta. Es más, yo diría que poner una respuesta que no sirve para resolver la pregunta es ruido innecesario. Lo que interesan son respuestas que SÍ responden la pregunta. Lo veo pues contraproducente y desde luego no es obligatorio de acuerdo a las normas del sitio.

Comment: @Jose estoy de acuerdo en algunos casos, pero siguiendo hablando de un caso general, también hay situaciones en las cuales citar una respuesta que no responde completamente puede ayudar a acotar la pregunta... Todo depende de cada caso en particular.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo Mariano. Cada usuario debe usar su mejor criterio.

Answer (score 2):

No debes duplicar preguntas pero sí puedes hacer tu pregunta.

Partes de unas premisas incompatibles.

- El problema X del usuario A es igual al problema X del usuario B.
- La respuesta Y soluciona un problema pero no el otro.

Esto es una contradicción, si fuesen problemas iguales todas las respuestas serían igual de válidas o inválidas para ambos problemas, pues son problemas iguales.

El hecho de que una respuesta solucione un problema y no el otro demuestra que son problemas diferentes y sus preguntas no son duplicadas.

Que haya una pregunta sobre cómo ordenar vectores en C++ no impide preguntar cómo hacer lo mismo en Java o Python.

Es más, se puede hacer una pregunta sobre cómo ordenarlos en Python con los elementos propios del lenguaje y otra sobre cómo hacerlo usando una librería como numpy, son cuestiones diferentes. Y son situaciones que suceden en la vida real. Es normal encontrarse con tener que hacer un trabajo contra un sistema que no se puede cambiar y te tienes que restringir a lo que hay. También es normal que tengas libertad para instalar lo que haga falta pero que te pidan lo máximo que la tecnología actual permite. Las dos situaciones son totalmente distintas y requieren preguntas y respuestas distintas.

Puedes preguntar cómo iniciar una comunicación en CORBA 1.0 y poner otra pregunta sobre cómo hacer lo mismo en CORBA 2.2; los cambios de una a otra fueron enormes.

Pero probablemente no tenga mucho sentido poner una pregunta sobre ordenación de vectores en Java 2 6.0 si ya hay una para Java 2 5.0

Ante la duda pregunta. Preguntar no es errar.

Answer (score -1):

No considero que sea necesaria una nueva pregunta, ya que se trata del mismo problema y de acuerdo a lo que dice en el [tour de Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) respecto a la respuesta aceptada:

> Aceptar una respuesta no quiere decir que sea la mejor, solo quiere
>   decir que **le sirvió a la persona que formuló la pregunta**.

Lo que da lugar a que tu puedas generar una nueva respuesta, exponiendo cómo esta solución resolvió el problema en común.

---

Claro está que, *si tienes mas información que pueda aportar una diferencia* a la pregunta existente, puedes entonces en este caso formular tu pregunta y colocar el enlace de la **pregunta relacionada**.